# Spring batch with two Data base

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

The main Moto is need to transfer the data from one data base to another date bade for that am going to write a batch program but spring batch is creating tables in both the data bases how to stop that

Comment: Maybe spell check before you submit question: data base -> database

Comment: spring batch does not create tables by itself. Please share your config to be able to help you.